# Problems saving images in VB .Net using multithreading

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, image

I've written a VB .Net program that does selective intensity pixel modification on graphic files. It's a lot faster than it was when I started (20 seconds vs 90 seconds), but the total time to process multiple images is still slow. I typically run 64 12 MP images, and it takes about 24 minutes to process them all. I thought that if I use multiple threads, each thread processing a subset of the total image set, I could speed things up, so I added multiple background workers. But when I run multiple threads from the program with Thread#.RunWorkerAsync(), the saved images are screwed up. Here's a "good" image, run in a single thread:

http://freegeographytools.com/good.jpg

And here's a typical example of the same image when two threads are running:

http://freegeographytools.com/bad.jpg

These results are essentially typical, but the "bad" image has a clean stripe near the bottom that looks correct; that doesn't normally appear on most images.
Each thread calls its own subroutine with independent variables, so there should be no variable "cross-contamination". While these results were obtained with images saved as JPG, I've gotten the same results with images saved as TIF files. I've also tried separating the images into different directories, and processing each directory simultaneously, each with its own thread - same result. To modify pixels, I've used GetPixel/SetPixel to change the pixel value, and also used LockBits to modify the image in a byte array - results are the same for both methods. One thread good, two+ thread bad. I'm sure it's something obvious, but I can't figure it out. Suggestions would very much be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to post relevant code for the multi-threaded case to get a good answer.

Comment: Please submit your code as the community can start to propose ideas about what the problem can be.

Answer (score 0):

If the application works in single threading, then there is probably some interference among threads. One possible source is at the file level. If you load an image from disk using the .net graphics class, that image file stays open. Without seeing the code I couldn't suggest anything specific, but this one thing that can cause a problem like you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, folks. In the process of preparing a code fragment to post here, discovered the problem. A variable (more specifically, a conversion matrix) that I thought was independent and unchanging was actually being modified in each of the subroutines. So some of the pixel conversions were being done with the wrong matrix, which resulted in the splotchy pixel appearance of the "bad" image. Just by making the matrix independent between the different subroutines, the problem disappeared, and I can now run multiple threads without issues. Thanks for your comments - just preparing to post the code led me to the answer.